# Change the background of every new button

Tags: java, android

```
for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
      LinearLayout row = new LinearLayout(this);
      row.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

      LinearLayout underRow = new LinearLayout(this);
      underRow.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
      for (int i = 0; i < MAX_BUTTONS; i++) {

//              String buttonID = "btn" + j + i;
//              int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(buttonID, "id","com.project.beacontreetech.doublecheckversion1");
          RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
          RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
          button = (Button) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.button_layout, buttonsContainer, false);
          // TextView textView = (TextView) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.text_view, buttonsContainer,false);
          int id1 , id2 ;
          id1 = i;
          id2 = j;
          StringBuilder append = new StringBuilder();
          append.append(id1);
          append.append(id2);

            int imgArrLength = imageList.length;
            for ( t=0; t < imgArrLength; t++){

            }


          String yo = (String.valueOf(append));
          int id = Integer.valueOf(String.valueOf(append));

          button.setHeight(buttonSize);
          button.setWidth(buttonSize);
          button.setOnClickListener(this);
          button.setId(id);


        if (button.getId() == 01){
              button.setBackgroundResource(imageList[1]);
          }
```

Comment: Please add an explanation of what you are trying to achieve and what problems you are having. Posting code does not give us enough information.

Comment: I created some button dynamically, then i used for loop to increment them, now i want to change the background of each buttons i created using the loop @Karakuri

Answer (score 0):

For set background image for button which is in drawable folder then use below code:

```
button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.new_todo_image);
```

For set color background you should use this:

```
button.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.Green));
```

your color.xml look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
    <resources>  
        <drawable name="red">#f00</drawable>  
        <drawable name="green">#0f0</drawable>  
        <drawable name="gray">#ccc</drawable>  
    </resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    if (button.getId() == 01){
          //to set background image on button 
          button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.your_image);

          //or set background color use 
          button.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.your_color));
    }
```

Comment: I tried the above code, it gave error because of the combination "01", works for only 00

Comment: I think 01 is only id of button, if its not working then you can generate button id  concatenation with string